# What does 都是套路 mean?

Tags: translation

I had a friend type it out, but Google translate said it meant "Routine", and she insisted that's not what it means.

Apparently it's slang?

Has anybody heard this before, and know what it translates into?

Comment: Without more context, I perceive nothing more than "routine".

Comment: Context: With American friend and Chinese friend, Chinese friend barely speaks english.  American friend mentions Chinese friend's name, and says gibberish.  We pretend to be smack talking the Chinese friend.  The Chinese friend says "都是套路" but Google Translate says "everything is routine", which makes no sense

Comment: Still makes not much sense to me. Maybe 都是套路 didn't refer to someone's name being called in gibberish, but other things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Literally, "it's all routine", which is now used online to mean "act according to scripts, not from heart". That is, you mindlessly follow what a book or someone else tells you to do, step by step, without any thinking from yourself.

I believe it originated from the routines to date girls. (I made this up) 1. get her out, 2. pick a restaurant that is quiet and posh, 3. "carelessly" drop something on the ground so you can touch her hand, etc, which eventually leads to get her to bed. So guys follow this routine mindlessly and girls recognise his behaviour "is all routine (to get me to bed)", not to start a serious relation.

Comment: I believe this to be the case.  The chinese friend in question is a girl and tends to make jokes like that.  She also said "Ai Mei", I'm not sure which characters they are, but they translated to "Ambiguous."  Do you know what that means?

Comment: I think “Ai Mei” refer to “暧昧” which means people have an affair. And, this is a picture describe the phrase "都是套路". http://goo.gl/wSwQcS

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that OP asked about a girl saying 'Ai Mei' to him (assume OP is a him), Ai Mei could mean unclear relationship, so I guess these two words 'Ai Mei' and 'Dou Shi Tao Lu' were said by the girl under the concern of sincereness of OP's pursue (if there were any). Hope this helps answer OP's questions :)

Comment: Yeah she refuses to explain anything further, and I am unavailable, so I figured she was playing games like that.  I just wasn't sure what level of worried I should be

Answer (score 2):

I've seen 套路 in gamer slang to mean something like `ways to play (the game/character etc)`. So something like:

> 这都是套路

could mean

> These are all possible ways to play (the game/character etc)

Answer (score 1):

套路means a series of skills and trick

Comment: That's what "routine" actually means. The "routine" entry in *New Oxford American Dictionary* says "a sequence of actions regularly followed; a fixed program; a set sequence in a performance such as a dance or comedy act".

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the close meaning of 都是套路 can be referred "It's trap".

Answer (score 0):

It means 用了很多计谋(intrigue,plot).for example, Teemo Dance in front of you, and there are a lots of mushrooms around him. you can say that 都是套路.

Answer (score 0):

套路：I think the closest in the Anglo-Saxon lexicon is :something lame or corny.
Come on. All your moves are so predictable. Try something more original !!

Answer (score 0):

Strategy. Another of those 'Internet lingo' that grew popular within the chinese circles

Source: http://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%A5%97%E8%B7%AF/19444463

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be the nearest word in English "Modus Operandi" for 
套路 .

Answer (score 0):

I am a chinese,but my english is poor.so by my words

都是套路:these are designed.

Answer (score -1):

Common tricks or old tricks.
I think your Chinese friend probably means "you're just kidding me".

Answer (score -1):

This word doesn't make sense

She is Express exclamation

Just like "oh my god!"   A more gentle expression